# Route generation or chooser in tinymce bundle with symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, tinymce

I'm working on sample application written with symfony2 and I want to add some cms funcionality (standard manage page entities) and the problem is routing in [tinymce](https://github.com/stfalcon/TinymceBundle) wysiwyg editor for links. It will be nice if user will be able to choose route to symfony application page when it want's to add link in the content. Is there a solution / plugin for that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a route exposing bundle with a plugin for TinyMCE but you can easily write one yourself with:

[FOSJSRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

For security reasons not all routes will be exposed by default. 
After installing the bundle as described in the [README](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown). Expose routes like this:

```
my_route_to_expose:
    pattern: /foo/{id}/bar
    defaults: { _controller: HelloBundle:Hello:index }
    options:
        expose: true
```